# Error Importing rpy

Tags: python, r

I'm getting this error message when trying to import rpy in the Python IDLE.  I know it's some sort of path error, can someone explain to me what this means and how to rectify it?  Thanks!

Unable to determine R version from the registry. Trying another method.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import rpy
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy.py", line 88, in <module>
    import win32api
ImportError: No module named win32api
```

Comment: Do you know if a the `win32api` module is installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error I'd say you are missing the `win32api` module. To fix this [install the Python for Windows extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/).

From the readme file:

> The SourceForge file system is horrible, making it very painful to 
>   locate the latest build - please follow the instructions below.
>        To download pywin32:
>
> - Select the "Browse All Files" link, then navigate to the "pywin32"   folder and select the latest available build (currently Build 217)
> - Select the installer executable for your system.  Note that there    is one download package for each supported version of Python -
>     please check what version of Python you have installed and    download
>     the corresponding package.
>
> Some packages have a 32bit and a 64bit version available - you must
>   download the one which corresponds to the Python you have installed. 
>   Even if you have a 64bit computer, if you installed a 32bit version of
>   Python you must install the 32bit version of pywin32.
>
> To determine what version of Python you have, just start Python and
>   look at the first line of the banner.  A 32bit build will look
>   something like:
>
> ```
> Python 2.7.2+ ... [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
>                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```
>
> While a 64bit build will look something like:
>
> ```
> Python 2.7.2+ ... [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```
>
> If the installation process informs you that Python is not found in
>   the  registry, it almost certainly means you have downloaded the wrong
>   version - either for the wrong version of Python, or the wrong
>   "bittedness".

Comment: Great! All I see on the sourceforge page is a readme.txt download. There must be something I'm missing here.

Comment: @Thetravellingfool To prevent you from having to do any more work than necessary, I've downloaded the readme.txt file and pasted it above. Perhaps you'd like me to come over and install it for you too?

Comment: I'm new to the programming world and to Source Forge in general.  It was a confusing process for me as I didn't see a "Browse All Files" link anywhere.  It's throwing a different error now so we must have done something in the right direction.  I appreciate the help but not the sarcasm.